# How I Can delete all record from child table in room?

Tags: android, android-room

I would like to use firebase to refresh my local DB.

I have 2 tables, one is the plants which have ID, Name... and the other one is the price which have the plantId in One to One relation.

I thought that, I can store firebase DB data in my Room db, but the local db doesn't use generated id, so the id as the same as the firebase id.

So when the plant data changes in firebase real time database, I delete all records from the the plant table in local db, and after that I insert the new plant records, but I would like to hold the second (Price) table records, which contains Plant id.
Actually my problem is: Room throws Exception, because it can't delete the plant table.

I read a lot, and I have found a tip, that I can set up onDelete = NO_ACTION but it isn't helped.

Could someone help, how can I solve this problem?

If I don't add data to Price table, that I can refresh the Plant table

```
My PlantEntity

@Entity(tableName = "plants")
public class PlantEntity {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

My PriceEntity

@Entity(tableName = "prices",
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = PlantEntity.class,
                        parentColumns = "id",
                        childColumns = "plant_id",
                        onDelete = NO_ACTION),
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = AmountUnitEntity.class,
                        parentColumns = "id",
                        childColumns = "amount_unit_id",
                        onDelete = NO_ACTION)})
public class PriceEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "min_price")
    private int minPrice;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "max_price")
    private int maxPrice;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "plant_id")
    private Long plantId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "amount_unit_id")
    private Long amountUnitId;

And my PlantDao

@Insert
    void insert(List<PlantEntity> plantEntityList);

    @Update
    void update(PlantEntity plantEntity);

    @Delete
    void delete(PlantEntity plantEntity);

    @Query("DELETE FROM plants")
    void deleteAll();
```

Comment: Hello there. First off, I hope you understand that Room works on top of **SQLite database**, the SQLite database is quite different from what Firebase is offering, Firebase Realtime database does not have **relations** . 
I am guessing you know these things. And for your question are you trying to delete the price table entries related to the plant on deleting a  `PlantEntity` from the table?

Comment: Yes I know the real time databse. And no, I would like to delete the Plant Entries , and hold the Price entries related to PlantEntity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain the PriceEnity row for a deleted plant then you could not define the ForeignKey to the plant, as it's the Foreignkey's constraint that is in conflict.

If you do not want to retain the PriceEntity then use `onDelete = CASCADE`, this will delete the children of the parent.

Comment: Thanks, yes I would like to retain the PriceEntity rows, and I also thought this solution, but it is a good idea , that I don't add any relations between tables, or this is the only solution?

Comment: @Andreas1234 you don't need to define Foreign Keys for relationships to exist. Adding Foreign Keys enforces a valid relationship. Not having a Foreign doesn't stop the retrieval of related data. An alternative could be to have a row for "NOT A PLANT" as the default value (can't use null because the parent index will be defined with NOT NULL, perhaps 0) and then use `on DELETE SET DEFAULT` (never tried this). The problem is that there doesn't appear to be any means to set a DEFAULT value via an Entity.